# SQL Pivot - nvarchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I want to pivot my data but I can have a aggregate function :(

[image]

```
SELECT [IdTask]
      ,[Name]
      ,[LogType]
      ,[Fr]
      ,[Input]
      ,[CreatedAt]
  FROM [dbo].[vRapport]
```

I want to have a result like this :
[image]

Someone have a idea to do this ?

Thx

Try Pivot but not working for me without sum() count()

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL 2012 SERVER

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a list of numbers for 1 until 10.

Then, you may use `MIN()` or `MAX()` for `nvarchar` columns.

```
SELECT [IdTask]
    , [Name]
    , [1]
    , [2]
    , [3]
    , [4]
    , [5]
    , [6]
    , [7]
    , [8]
    , [9]
    , [10]
FROM
(
SELECT [IdTask]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [CreatedAt]) AS RowNum
    , [Name]
    , [Fr]
FROM [dbo].[vRapport]
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Fr)
    FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
) AS PivotTable;
```

If you wish to start from the query you provided, you may use CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [IdTask]
      ,[Name]
      ,[LogType]
      ,[Fr]
      ,[Input]
      ,[CreatedAt]
  FROM [dbo].[vRapport]
)
SELECT [IdTask]
    , [Name]
    , [1]
    , [2]
    , [3]
    , [4]
    , [5]
    , [6]
    , [7]
    , [8]
    , [9]
    , [10]
FROM
(
SELECT [IdTask]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [CreatedAt]) AS RowNum
    , [Name]
    , [Fr]
FROM CTE
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MIN(Fr)
    FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
) AS PivotTable;
```

You may read more on `ROW_NUMBER()` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16